# Objc: convert unsigned long to float

Tags: objective-c, casting

I'm making a calculation on the progress a download has, but can't seem to cast to a float. The progress is indicated by a float between 0 and 1.
The current unsigned longs that are coming in are:

totalBytesWritten = 6043903

totalBytesExpectedToWrite = 11545769

To get a number between 0 and 1 I perform the calculation:

6043903/11545769

This expected result is: 0,523473404 **BUT** the given result is 0.000000

Below the function where I try to calculate the progress:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    NSLog(@"%qi/%qi = %f", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, (float)(totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite));
}
```

Anyone knows how to get my calculation right?

Comment: try changing `(totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite)` to `(totalBytesWritten*1.0/totalBytesExpectedToWrite)`

Comment: @Novarg Perfect! It worked instantly, thanks for your answer.